# Переменную input в value чекбокса

Tags: html, css

Господа помогите пожалуйста. Мне нужно, чтобы value чекбокса содержало value инпута. Как это можно воплотить в жизнь. Через форму не получилось, пытался сделать переменную инпута равной переменной чекбокса и тоже ничего не вышло.

Как то вот так пытался: $order = $amount1; где order это чекбокс, а amount1 это инпут.

```
 <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input  type="checkbox" class="form" name="order">
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount1">
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Так же пытался вводить в value(чекбокса) пхп код содержащий переменную инпута(тоесть с name инпута) и всё равно ничего, уже все перепробовал и никак.

Опишу даже суть идеи, чтобы было прям вот понятно, что я хочу сделать. Вообщем есть сайт-магазин с мелким оптом. Товар 1 вида но разных цветов поэтому делать корзину ну я считаю незачем. На нем вообщем фотки с цветами и подписан id цвета и внизу есть чекбокс и инпут, в котором по задумке клиент должен вводить количество товара. Далее когда клиент выставит чекбоксы на нужных товарах, а так же выставит количество он доходит до формы оформления и всё это отправляется в базу sql.

[image: Вот скрин, на нем всё немного топорно, но для понимания сути пойдет]

Comment: Не по теме вашего вопроса, но в помощь. Какое количество позиций товаров? Товары все на одной странице или какой-то фильтр есть и/или пейджер? "Товар 1 вида но разных цветов поэтому делать корзину ну я считаю незачем." - это не вы должны решать, а пользователи. Убрав (не добавив) корзину вы тем самым нарушите стандартные паттерны пользования и поверьте конверсию вам это не добавит

Comment: Ну я вас понял, спасибо за совет, просто уже решил сделать так и поставил перед собой именно вот такую задачу)

Answer (score 1):

используйте в названиях элементов формы код товара:

```
<div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input  type="checkbox" class="form" name="order[10]">
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount[10]" >
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

и при обработки вы будете иметь 2 массива order и amount. если order[10] отмечен, тогда берете количество из значения amount[10]

Comment: лучше name="order[10]" и name="amount[10]"

Comment: или `item[10][order]` и `item[10][amount]`

Comment: подправил в ответе

Comment: Спасибо за совет, сделал как вы написали, но у меня не получается передать это значение в mysql, не могли бы подсказать, что делаю не так.

if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
   $order = $_POST["order"];
   $amount = $_POST["amount"];
if($order)  foreach($_POST['order'] as $checkbox){
  $orderSep = implode (",", $order);
}
$success = $mysqli-> query ("INSERT INTO `orders`.`orders` (`ID`, `Name`, `Email`, `Adress`, `ContactNum`, `Order`, `Payment`, `Time`) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$adress."', '".$contact."', '".$orderSep."', '".$optionSep."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

Comment: изначально всё нужно переписать... но  из того, что есть 1) не понятно зачем  $orderSep = implode (",", $order); 2) цикл не так, нужно foreach($_POST['order'] as $nom=>$checkbox) ... $amount = $_POST['amount'][$nom], .... 3) более правильно и надежней использовать для запросов PDO

Comment: Ну про PDO я понял в сл. раз буду делать так, но вот если сейчас работать с тем, что есть. Я вписал всё, что нужно но всё равно не получается. Всё остальное, что я делал у меня отправляется и работает, а тут ну прям никак и я не пойму. Уже пробовал по всякому всё равно никак. Я же правильно понял в sql через INSERT_INTO я отправляю .'"$order"'. и должно вот будет отправится значение инпута?

Comment: Implode был по аналогии с моей предыдущей задачей. Мне нужно было отправить значения нескольких чекбоксов и они не отправлялись пока не преобразовал все значения в строку с помощью implode